# Drawing rectangle on leaflet by giving coordinate

Tags: leaflet

i know the syntax to draw rectangle on leaflet by giving coordinate.
here is the sample code which i can use to draw rectangle on leaflet by giving coordinate.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([53.902257, 27.561640], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var bounds = [[53.912257, 27.581640], [53.902257, 27.561640]];
var rect = L.rectangle(bounds, {color: 'blue', weight: 1}).on('click', function (e) {
    // There event is event object
    // there e.type === 'click'
    // there e.lanlng === L.LatLng on map
    // there e.target.getLatLngs() - your rectangle coordinates
    // but e.target !== rect
    console.info(e);
}).addTo(map);
```

my coordinate look like `LatLng(-37.77353, 175.26882),LatLng(-37.77285, 175.26882),LatLng(-37.77285, 175.27097),LatLng(-37.77353, 175.27097)`

but if anyone see the above coordinate store in bounds variable then there two set of lat lang specified but mine is 4 set.

just tell me how could i push this kind of latlang `LatLng(-37.77353, 175.26882),LatLng(-37.77285, 175.26882),LatLng(-37.77285, 175.27097),LatLng(-37.77353, 175.27097)` to draw circle on my map ?

the issue is over because i had doubt to draw rectangle on map with big coordinates and i tried and got the success. here is small code attached.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
        alert("Drawing rectabgle!");

//var bounds = [[53.912257, 27.581640], [53.902257, 27.561640]];
var bounds = [[-37.77367, 175.27043], [-37.77261, 175.27043],[-37.77261,175.27313],[-37.77367,175.27313]];        
var rect = L.rectangle(bounds, {color: 'blue', weight: 1}).on('click', function (e) {
    // There event is event object
    // there e.type === 'click'
    // there e.lanlng === L.LatLng on map
    // there e.target.getLatLngs() - your rectangle coordinates
    // but e.target !== rect
    console.info(e);
}).addTo(map);

    });
}); 

http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/yyetbb1j/1/
```

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth-example.html

Comment: How will you use 4 coordinates for one circle? When drawing a circle in Leaflet you specify the center latLng and the circle radius.

Comment: i like to use 4 coordinate to draw rectangle not circle.

Comment: Ok... In your question it says "... to draw circle on my map?" What is the link to leaflet example for?

Comment: see this code how rectangle is drawn on map `var bounds = [[54.559322, -5.767822], [56.1210604, -3.021240]];
L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
` but when i try to capture bound when user end drawing rectangle on map then i get this bound `LatLng(-37.77353, 175.26882),LatLng(-37.77285, 175.26882),LatLng(-37.77285, 175.27097),LatLng(-37.77353, 175.27097)` my question is how to add big bound to draw rectangle?

Comment: check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/yyetbb1j/ draw rectangle and see what coordinate u will get. suppose if i store that big coordinate then how could draw rectangle by that coordinate later? help please.

Answer (score 2):

Try drawing a "polygon". See [Leaflet API](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon)

Comment: see this code how rectangle is drawn on map `var bounds = [[54.559322, -5.767822], [56.1210604, -3.021240]];
L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
` but when i try to capture bound when user end drawing rectangle on map then i get this bound `LatLng(-37.77353, 175.26882),LatLng(-37.77285, 175.26882),LatLng(-37.77285, 175.27097),LatLng(-37.77353, 175.27097)` my question is how to add big bound to draw rectangle?

Comment: check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/yyetbb1j/ draw rectangle and see what coordinate u will get. suppose if i store that big coordinate then how could draw rectangle by that coordinate later? help please.